# Python 3 concurrent.futures - process for loop in parallel

Tags: python-3.x, concurrent.futures

If I have understood correctly how the `concurrent.futures` module in Python 3 works, the following code:

```
import concurrent.futures
import threading

# Simple function returning a value
def test(i):

    a = 'Hello World\n'
    return a


def main():
    output1 = list()

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:

        # psdd iterator to test function
        for out1 in executor.map(test, range(0, 10)):
            # append returned result
            output1.append(out1)

            # confirm output
            print(output1)
            print("Task Executed {}".format(threading.current_thread()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

...performs the following functions:

1. Passes a for loop to the function called `test()`.
2. Processes the loop in parallel, rather than in serial.

However, what I really want is to process the loop in parallel in my `main()` function as so:

```
import concurrent.futures
import threading


def main():
    output1 = list()

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:

        # psdd iterator to test function
        for out1 in executor.submit(range(0, 10)):

            a = 'Hello World\n'
            # append returned result
            output1.append(a)

            # confirm output
            print(output1)
            print("Task Executed {}".format(threading.current_thread()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

...this however produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\HTPC Scripts\WebGrab Plus\TESTTESTTEST2.py", line 221, in <module>
    main()
  File "G:\HTPC Scripts\WebGrab Plus\TESTTESTTEST2.py", line 209, in main
    for out1 in executor.submit(range(0, 10)):
TypeError: 'Future' object is not iterable
```

What do I need to amend in my code?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by **what I really want is to process the loop in parallel in**? Could you explain more?

Comment: Hi  - so instead of starting at 0 and working through the loop sequentially 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 etc so that only one pass of the loop is 'live' at any one time, i want passes 0 to 10 to run at the same time on different threads. Does that make sense?

Comment: Well `executor.map` already apply a function `test` to each element in the iterable concurrently. Still not clear..

Comment: 'However, what I really want is to process the loop in parallel in my main() function as so:' - what is not clear about that? I am not asking whether or not test is passed a loop concurrently. I already know what it is...what I am saying is, once more for clarity: I do not wish to process a concurrent iterable in test(), i wish to process one directly in main(). How do I do this? Any other observations/statements/questions are a diversion from this. As is often stated in a passive aggressive manner on SO - this is not a code writing service. I have a very specific issue i require help with....

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter whether you use `submit` or `map`, you *always* have to use a callable (such as a function) as the first argument.

Python does allow nested functions (also take note of the way to use `Futures`);

```
import concurrent.futures


def main():

    def worker(arg):
        return str(arg) + ' Hello World!'

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as e:
        fut = [e.submit(worker, i) for i in range(10)]
        for r in concurrent.futures.as_completed(fut):
            print(r.result())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The only way to define a callable in-place is with a `lambda` expression, but those have significant limitations.